# Detalles de un Producto Vuejs

Tags: javascript, mongodb, vue.js

Quiero mostrar los detalles de un producto, pero no lo he logrado que me aparezca la información. Estoy trabajando con Vue Mongo Node y Express
Cuando le doy `http://localhost:3000/item/5aa811e5aa7f7d414c707127` aparece la información de la base de datos, pero cuando lo pongo como ruta para conocer más detalles del producto no sale nada y dice `bundle.js:1320 GET http://localhost:3000/detailsitem/item/5aa811e5aa7f7d414c707127 404 (Not Found)` que no lo encuentra cuando si está la información de la base de datos. ¿Cómo hago para que me muestre la información del producto?  Ya tengo que lo reconozca por la ID, pero es como si no reconociera la api.

Este es el principal.

```
<template>
  <div>

    <div class="row p-4">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1 class="title">Juicilicious</h1>
        <router-link :to="{ name: 'CreateItem' }" class="btn btn-primary float-right mt-2 btn-create">
          Create Item
        </router-link>
      </div>
    </div><br />

    <table class="table table-hover table-bordered listado">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>ID</td>
          <td>Item Name</td>
          <td>Item Category</td>
          <td>Item Image</td>
          <td>Actions</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="item in items">
          <td>{{ item._id }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.category }}</td>
          <td><img class="item-image" :src="'../public/images/' + item.image " /></td>
          <td>
            <router-link :to="`/detailsitem/item/${item._id}`" class="btn btn-primary btn-create">View</router-link>




          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default{
    name:'app',
    data(){
      return {
        items:[]
      };
    },
    created: function (){
      var vm=this;
      axios.get('http://localhost:3000/item').then(function(response){
        console.log(response.data);
        vm.items=response.data;


      })
    }
  }
</script>
```

Y este es el de los detalles

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>Show Item</h1>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-10"></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><router-link :to="{ name: 'DisplayItem' }" class="btn btn-create">Return to Items</router-link></div>
        </div>

        <form v-on:submit.prevent="updateItem">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Item Name</label>
                 <div>{{item.name}}</div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label name="product_price">Item Price</label>
               <div>{{item.price}}</div>
            </div>


        </form>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

    export default{
        data(){
            return {
        items:[]
      };
        },

        created: function(){
            this.getItem();
        },

        methods: {
            getItem()
            {
              let url = 'http://localhost:3000/item/' + this.$route.params.id;
                this.axios.get(url).then((response) => {
                    this.item = response.data;
                    console.log(response.data);
                });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

También tengo estás rutas

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
Vue.use(VueRouter);


import VueAxios from 'vue-axios';
import axios from 'axios';
Vue.use (VueAxios, axios);

import App from './App.vue';

import DisplayItem from './components/displayitem.vue';
import CreateItem from './components/createitem.vue';
import DetailsItem from './components/detailsitem.vue'

const routes =[
{
  name:'DisplayItem',
  path:'/',
  component:DisplayItem
},

{
  name:'CreateItem',
  path: '/create/item',
  component:CreateItem
},

{
    name:'DetailsItem',
    path: '/detailsitem/item/:id',
    component: DetailsItem
}
];

const router = new VueRouter({
 mode: 'history', routes: routes
  });


new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router: router,
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

Agradezco la ayuda!

Comment: Esa api tiene un get?

Comment: Sii  axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/item/` + this.$route.params.id)

Comment: Si, esa es tu llamada, pregunto si la api tiene un get..

Comment: El problema podría ser desde express que no está usando el método